# Как импортировать дамп БД при помощи DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, импорт, datagrip

Решил поучиться SQL по книге Алана Бьюли, скачал учебную БД, но не ясно как ее импортировать при помощи DataGrip на бесплатную БД от Heroku. БД MySQL.

линк дампа: https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596520847/

Answer (score 2):

- На пустой схеме вызовите контекстное меню, `Restore with mysql`
- Выберите файл с вашим дапмом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]